# How to change range of "bake sound to f curves"?

Tags: animation, audio, fcurves

Alright, Im trying to modify the "damp" parameter of a particle system in accordance with the beats of an audio file. So far, I "insert keyframe" on the damp parameter, go to F curves and then select "bake sound to f curves."

My issue is it then only modulates between 0-1. I need the damp to modulate between 0.152 and maybe 0.4.

How can I alter the range of bake sound to f curves in Blender 2.8?

Comment: either by scaling and moving the f-curve on the Y axis or using a curve modifier (either Limits or Envelope)

Answer (score 2):

Add an Envelope modifier to the F-curve, and add one control point. Change the min and max values to flatten or raise the amplitude of curves and change Reference value to reposition the central axis of the curves